# Sculpting doesn't work. Blender 2.9

Tags: mesh, sculpting

so i wanted to try out sculpting with blender. Created a new project (everything is at factory settings) and added a simple cube. Went into sculpt mode but none of the tools seem to do anything and even after 2 hours of trying so many different things, i can't get it to work.

Do you guys have any possible solutions?

The tools just aren't doing anything on any Meshes i'm trying to sculpt.

Comment: Have you subdivided them? If you try sculpting a simple cube nothing will happen because there are just 8 vertices for the sculpting tools to try to deform. Select your cube in edit mode, right-click > subdivide and increase the number of cuts to 10 in the popup in the bottom left corner of the screen. Then try again!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96306/sculpt-tool-not-working, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/the-normal-brush-in-sculpt-mode-on-blender-doesnt-work, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105458/no-sculpting-shown-in-sculpt-mode, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124558/in-clipping-border-mode-sculpt-tool-has-no-effect-help-is-much-appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Select your cube, press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then right click on your cube and choose

[image]

subdivide.

Then click that little arrow in the left lower corner:

[image]

Enter 20 in number of cuts and try to sculpt again.

[image]